# Need help formatting/parsing this list

Tags: python, json, tuples

I'm not a developer so sorry if this is a dumb question or if my terminology is incorrect. I'm writing a script to make calls to our CMDB's API but i'm not sure how to handle the data that is being sent back from it. It appears to be a list type but I can't reference anything by key names. Is there a way to convert it to something that i can easily manipulate and pull data out of?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

r=requests.post('API.URL', data={'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id':'#######', 'username': 'user', 'password': 'password'})
json_data = json.loads(r.content)
token = json_data['access_token']
data ={
  "filters": [
    {
      "fieldId": "937905400191ae67dd03ab4b79968fcbaa264b1a75",
      "operator": "eq",
      "value": "hostname"
    }
  ],
  "fields":[
    '9426b6ddf3cb971488517145e39efc5aa7f16fec46',
    '9343f8800b3917f26533954918a6388ae8c863507f',
    '9379053db492ece14816704ef5a9e3e567e217511b',
    '9343f93fc4c8422bcf24e74a9a86035bb7d0248b00',
    '941ba290776d6f51ce35664246927b958330a753b2'
  ],
  "association": "Configuration Item",
  "busObId": "93dada9f640056ce1dc67b4d4bb801f69104894dc8",
  "includeAllFields": 'false',
  "pageNumber": 0,
  "pageSize": 300,
  "scope": "Global",
  "scopeOwner": "(None)",
  "searchName": "APItest"
}
payload = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'bearer '+token}
search=requests.post('http://API.URL', headers=headers, data=payload)
search_json = json.loads(search.content)
bo = search_json['businessObjects']
print(bo)
```

Here's the response:

```
[
    {
        "busObRecId": "9423ad7d617390fdc956ee4302a69d0ccf1a37a4c1",
        "hasError": false,
        "links": [
            {
                "url": "http://URL",
                "name": "Delete Record"
            }
        ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "displayName": "Business Sponsor",
                "name": "Business Sponsor",
                "value": "",
                "html": null,
                "dirty": false,
                "fieldId": "9426b6ddf3cb971488517145e39efc5aa7f16fec46"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Owned By",
                "name": "Owned By",
                "value": "John Doe",
                "html": null,
                "dirty": false,
                "fieldId": "9343f8800b3917f26533954918a6388ae8c863507f"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Asset Status",
                "name": "Asset Status",
                "value": "Active",
                "html": null,
                "dirty": false,
                "fieldId": "9379053db492ece14816704ef5a9e3e567e217511b"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Description",
                "name": "Description",
                "value": "Automation Server",
                "html": null,
                "dirty": false,
                "fieldId": "9343f93fc4c8422bcf24e74a9a86035bb7d0248b00"
            },
            {
                "displayName": "Data Center Location",
                "name": "Data Center Location",
                "value": "",
                "html": null,
                "dirty": false,
                "fieldId": "941ba290776d6f51ce35664246927b958330a753b2"
            }
        ],
        "errorMessage": null,
        "busObPublicId": "9423ad7d617390fdc956ee4302a69d0ccf1a37a4c1",
        "busObId": "93dada9f640056ce1dc67b4d4bb801f69104894dc8",
        "errorCode": null
    }
]
```

`type()` shows the object `bo` as a list and `len()` says it only has one element so I'm not sure how to pull data out of it without hacking away at it stripping out characters.

Comment: It's a list containing one dictionary item....

Comment: `bo[0]['busObRecId'] == '9423ad7d617390fdc956ee4302a69d0ccf1a37a4c1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cannot reference anything by key names is the fact that your output is a list. A list which is only containing one single dictionary element. If you print out

```
bo[0]
```

you get the whole data, without the [ and ] symbols. As for the dictionary now we can access different elements by keys, e.g.:

```
print(bo["busObId"])
```

will return the following value:

```
93dada9f640056ce1dc67b4d4bb801f69104894dc
```

Let's say you would want to print out the fieldId of the first element of "fields". You can do it the following way:

```
print(bo[0]["fields"][0]["fieldId"])
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This helps a ton, Thank you! Trying print(bo["busObId"]) gives me an error but the second format you posted works perfectly.